Are there any assets you can invest your retirement accounts in that take advantage of the illiquidity premium?
I have various retirement accounts (e.g. Roth IRA, 401k) that I have no intention of withdrawing money from until I reach retirement age, which is multiple decades from now.
But it seems like the most common investment options for these accounts are very liquid assets that you can sell within a business day or two, typically some blend of public equity and bonds, where the allocation evolves as you move closer to retirement age.
It seems to me that this is suboptimal, because the ability to liquidate these assets is of little use to me until I get closer to retirement age. There should be some sort of deal out there where I could take advantage of the illiquidity premium, that is, the fact that I'm willing to have my money locked down for an extended period of time in exchange for a higher rate of return.
Are there any sort of assets like this that are accessible to "normal" people who don't have multiple millions of dollars?

Can't do it with a retirement account, but lots of people invest in real estate as a sort of savings plan. Those would definitely be less liquid. Although, that has other risks/rewards to consider.

Self-directed IRAs can enable investments in various illiquid assets.

@Peter Olson : what do you have in mind? I don't think there are any obvious choices where the illiquidity provides a better return at the same or lower risk than your run of the mill ETF.


But it seems like the most common investment options for these
accounts are very liquid assets that you can sell within a business
day or two, typically some blend of public equity and bonds, where the
allocation evolves as you move closer to retirement age.

while your ability to pull the money out of a retirement account before reaching retirement age comes with a hefty tax and penalty, that doesn't mean that your investments are unchanging for decades.
I worked for a company that once you had something of the order of 10K or 20K in the 401(k) account you could move beyond the standard dozen investment options and could tap into anything the brokerage company could sell. That meant stocks and a who host of mutual funds and ETFs. That meant that even 401(k) account could invest in anything an IRA account could do.

There should be some sort of deal out there where I could take
advantage of the illiquidity premium, that is, the fact that I'm
willing to have my money locked down for an extended period of time in
exchange for a higher rate of return.

Now it sounds like you want to invest in long term CDs. or long term government bonds.
Investing in stocks or stock funds have zero guaranteed return. Yet you want a higher rate of return because you can't sell your investment.
The 401(k) or IRA don't require you to not buy and sell investments, you can do that dozens of times over the decades. You just can't convert the funds to non-retirement funds without that tax and penalty hit.

Agreed. Most 401ks will let you move money between their investment options upon request, though there may be limitations such as only being able to exchange funds between any pair of investments once a month. If you want to actively trade, the 401K is not the place to do it. But if you just want to maintain your investment profile - that is, rebalance - that's usually possible and often quite easy. For me, all it takes is hitting the 401K services website. And in my case, the investment options offered within the 401K are much broader than I will ever want to use. I presume IRAs are similar.
